How to get the hostname of a local server in my LAN using its IP address?
According to Get the Hostname From an IP Address on the LAN, I can get the hostname of an IP address of a local server either using the nmblookup or nbtscan. However, these commands are not getting a reply (see below). I can ping 192.168.1.50 and ssh into it as it is a Ubuntu 24.04 Server. Why am I not getting the hostname and how to fix this issue?
$ nmblookup -A 192.168.1.50
Looking up status of 192.168.1.50
No reply from 192.168.1.50
$
$ nbtscan 192.168.1.50
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 192.168.1.50

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$
$ ping 192.168.1.50
PING 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=6.87 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.34 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.91 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=3.39 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=3.37 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.50: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.78 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.50 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.778/3.942/6.869/1.529 ms
$
$ avahi-resolve -a 192.168.1.50
Failed to resolve address '192.168.1.50': Timeout reached

PS. I am aware of How to find a computer name in a LAN from the IP address? but the answers there do not address my query.
I wonder if the setting in this file is causing the issue, hmm?
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd sss
group:          files systemd sss
shadow:         files sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mymachines
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
automount:      sss

The ubuntu 22.04 desktop client IP is 192.168.1.170 and it is connected via wifi to the router 192.168.1.1. The Ubuntu 24.04 server is connected to the router via ethernet and its IP is 192.168.1.50. Its stub resolver is running on port 53. Also, I am setting it up as a local DNS on port 3000.

Did you try avahi-resolve-host-name -a 192.168.1.50? You may need to install avahi-daemon on both the client and server if not already installed.

@mpboden avahi-resolve did not work either.

host 192.168.1.50 Does that work?

@Morbius1 It returned Host 50.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN).

We are running out of options here. If ping works tell it to list the associated host: ping -H 192.168.1.50

@Morbius1 ping: invalid option -- 'H'

@Morbius1 do u think /etc/nsswitch.conf is causing the issue? I have added its content above.

Maybe I'm missing something, but if my rough understanding of NetBIOS is correct (I've never dealt with it in reality so bear with me if I'm wrong) you shouldn't expect the server to reply with a NetBIOS name unless it's a Windows machine or something like Samba is enabled on the server, which if I recall correctly implements NetBIOS on Linux machines in order to communicate via Samba itself. So is the server a Windows machine? Or, in case it's a Linux machine, does it have Samba enabled?

@kros The client is a linux desktop using Ubuntu 22.04 and samba is not installed. I am clueless as to why these commands yield no results from this client.

host and nslookup
Typically, when looking up a hostname, you'll use either the host or nslookup command, such as the following:
host 192.168.1.50
nslookup 192.168.1.50

But for these to work, the hostname for these hosts need to be registered with a DNS server or entered into your /etc/hosts file. If you have a local DNS server on your network, then you can register the hosts there. Otherwise, your router may be configured as a DNS resolver and can be configured there.
nmblookup and nbtscan
You indicated nmblookup and nbtscan are not replying. This is because both of these commands use the NetBIOS over TCP/IP protocol to lookup NetBIOS names, which are not necessarily the same as the hostname. Basically, NetBIOS provides a naming service in a Windows environment. In order to work with Ubuntu hosts, you'll need to configure Samba and windbind on each host.
nmap
You state that the answers here did not give you what you want. But the nmap command should work and return information with the hostname. For example, I can enter the following command with results that include the hostname:
$ nmap -sn 192.168.10.20
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-28 23:14 PDT
Nmap scan report for gamekeeper.localdomain (192.168.10.20)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.00 seconds

To extract the hostname out of this, I can run the following command:
$ nmap -sn 192.168.10.20 | grep 192.168.10.20 | awk '{print $5}'
gamekeeper.localdomain

If nmap isn't installed on your computer, you can install it with sudo apt install nmap.
Avahi
Another option is to use Avahi, which facilitates service discovery on a local network via the mDNS/DNS-SD protocol suite. Similarly, you may be familiar with Bonjour, which is Apple's technology known as zero-configuration networking to allow discovery of devices and services on a local network using standard IP protocols.
You've indicated in your original post that the output of avahi-resolve -a 192.168.1.50 times out. This can be caused by the host not being reachable on the network. However, you say you can ping and ssh into it, so I suspect that the problem is because you don't have avahi-daemon installed on the host you're querying.
By default, avahi-daemon is installed on Ubuntu Destktop 22.04 and 24.04, but it's not installed on Ubuntu Server 22.04 and 24.04. Your post says you're trying to lookup the hostname of a "server" and you're querying from a "desktop". So, first things first, install avahi-daemon on your server with the following commands:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install avahi-daemon

Afterwards, lookup the status and you'll see the service running:
$ systemctl status avahi-daemon
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-09-18 22:10:08 PDT; 1 month 9 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● avahi-daemon.socket
   Main PID: 538 (avahi-daemon)
     Status: "avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 19106)
     Memory: 2.2M
        CPU: 1min 30.056s
     CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
             ├─538 "avahi-daemon: running [gamekeeper.local]"
             └─566 "avahi-daemon: chroot helper"

Finally, from your Desktop client, you can resolve the hostname with:
avahi-resolve -a 192.168.1.50

As an example:
avahi-resolve -a 192.168.10.20
192.168.10.20   gamekeeper.local

You've updated your question indicating that your Desktop is connected via WiFi and your server is connected via Ethernet. The reason mDNS is not working is probably due to your router either blocking mDNS over WiFi or packets are being dropped.
See this Superuser question/answer for more info:
Why do some WiFi routers block multicast packets going from wired to wireless?
Therefore, as a test, try connecting the Desktop computer to your router via Ethernet and try resolving your hostname again.

As a side note, your /etc/nsswitch.conf file is configured correctly.
If you check this answer that I wrote for someone asking about resolving local hostnames, I outline and explain what the hosts line means in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file.

For more information about Avahi, visit avahi.org and see this AskUbuntu answer. Also, this answer has some great info on mDNS.

Running nmap from this client did not return a hostname of 192.168.1.50  Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.50 Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.01 seconds.

The client already had avahi-daemon installed and systemctl status avahi-daemon showed that it was running. The command $ dpkg -l | grep avahi-daemon  returned  ii  avahi-daemon  0.8-5ubuntu5.2  amd64  Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon. Hence I don't understand why the avahi-resolve -a 192.168.1.50 gives Failed to resolve address '192.168.1.10': Timeout reached.

If none of the tools mentioned in this answer work, it means that probably: 1) you have no DNS running in your network or the target IP is not registered in the DNS; 2) the target machine is not running Samba so it has no NetBIOS hostname. If this is the case, your machine simply has no externally (ie. outside the machine) available hostname at all (it doesn't necessarily have to). It only has its internal hostname, which you can learn eg. by logging into the machine and typing the hostname command. But this may have no meaning outside the machine.

@SunBear What is the IP address of your Desktop client? Are the hosts on the same or different subnets? Please describe your network setup. How are the two hosts connected? Through a switch, through a router, hardwired, via WiFi, or directly connected together with an Ethernet cable? Please update your original question with this information.

@mpboden I have updated my question with the info that you requested, I hope it is sufficient.

If you have nmap installed, try:
nmap -sL 192.168.1.50

Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-29 06:06 GMT
Nmap scan report for examplehost.examplefqdn.com (192.168.1.50)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.02 seconds

Reverse lookup relies on your local DNS server (which may be on your router) knowing the hostnames for IP addresses on your network. There are several reasons why the DNS may not know the hostname of an IP. If DNS correctly configured to resolve this host, restarting the networking on your server (or rebooting) will refresh DHCP on the server and give the DNS server a chance to update.
You could try:
nmap -sL 192.168.1.0/24

Look for correctly identified hostnames in the list: this will tell you if any host on your network can resolve an IP to a hostname using DNS.
